# Mimecast - How to add a new email signature

Tags: email

I have logged to the Mimecast administration console on their website but I cannot find where to edit the default signature that all personnel is using. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, this is to be found in the Stationary tab